# VIM - remove match of a group

Tags: vim, neovim

I have a small function to underline every word like the word under my cursor:

```
function! HighlightWordUnderCursor()
  hi MatchWord NONE
  let disabled_ft = ["qf", "fugitive", "nerdtree", "gundo", "diff", "fzf", "floaterm"]
  if &diff || &buftype == "terminal" || index(disabled_ft, &filetype) >= 0
    return
  endif
  if getline(".")[col(".")-1] !~# '[[:punct:][:blank:]]'
    hi MatchWord cterm=undercurl gui=undercurl guibg=#3b404a
    exec 'match' 'MatchWord' '/\V\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>/'
  else
    match none
  endif
endfunction

augroup MatchWord
  autocmd!
  autocmd! CursorHold,CursorHoldI * call HighlightWordUnderCursor()
augroup END
```

However, when in diff mode, it still matches but it's black on a yellow changed line. How can I fix it? Thanks.

[image: ss]

Worth noting: on non-diff lines, the highlighting is not happening as expected.

Comment: why do you have a function for that anyway? why not just use `*`?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I wish I could downvote your comment.

Comment: I am sorry that you feel that way. However I am not trying to bully you, I am seriously asking. I am fairly certain you know of that possibility. That is why I wonder what the (probably valid) reason behind this is...

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo look at the autocmd. I'm copying a vscode behaviour of marking the symbol under the cursor, not searching for it, I don't want to pollute my `@/` register, this is very useful to see similar keywords in your code.

Comment: thanks. Your check of `&diff` actually looks right. Have you tried adding a breakpoint to see, if it really skips the `if` block? `breakadd func HighlightWordUnderCursor`

Comment: It enters the `if` block, I added echo and the echo is outputted. I think there's actually no highlight, but the match still exists.

Comment: Don't you need a `match none` there too? I mean I don't think so, but kind of the only guess left. And are you sure, the diff has no problems if you remove that code?